# How to show an array of images in other page in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a page that handles **FlatList** and An array of images with id,
I want when the user clicks a specific element in the **FlatList** to show him some element on that array on another page based on the id. I have a page that handles **FlatList** and An array of images with id,
I want when the user clicks a specific element in the **FlatList** to show him some element on that array on another page based on the id.

```
const List_of_Sories = ({ navigation }) => {
    const imgs = [
        {
            img: require("../../assets/favicon.png"),
            id: 1,
            hhh:{
                text:"hello"
            }
        },
        {
            img: require("../../assets/favicon.png"),
            id: 2
        },
        {
            img: require("../../assets/favicon.png"),
            id: 3
        }
    ]
    return (
        <Block center middle >
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    vertical={true}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    data={imgs}
                    keyExtractor={(images) => images.name}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("allStories",{id:item.id})} >
                            <Image source={item.img}
                                key={index}
                                style={{
                                    width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2,
                                    height: 300,
                                    borderWidth: 5,
                                    borderColor: "red",
                                    margin: 4
                                }}
                            />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )}
                />
            </View>
        </Block >
    )
}
```

I want to show element here, if the id matches the clicked element I want to show the element that is === to the id
I want to show element here, if the id matches the clicked element I want to show the element that is === to the idI want to show element here if the id matches the clicked element I want to show the element that is === to the id.

```
export default function componentName({ route: { params } }) {
    const { id } = params;
    alert(id)
    return (
        <View >
            <Text>preview post with id {id}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Do you want to show element on another page or this page?

Comment: I want to show them on other page

Comment: use navigation library

Comment: Do you want to just show clicked item on the next page or complete array?

Comment: Completely array just give code example